# How to mock Google Api Discovery HttpResponseSequence

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api, mocking, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to use [Google Api Discovery HttpMockSequence](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/mocks), but I keep getting the following error:

```
InvalidJsonError: 
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
googleapiclient.discovery: INFO: URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/webmasters/v3/rest
googleapiclient.discovery: ERROR: Failed to parse as JSON: /home/user/development/projectname/tests/build_response_data.json
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------
```

here is what I have/trying to do:

tests.py

```
build_response = self.datafile('build_response_data.json')
request_data = self.datafile('saved_request_data.json')

http_auth = HttpMockSequence([
    ({'status': '200'}, build_response),
    ({'status': '200'}, request_data)
])

service = build('webmasters',
                'v3',
                http=http_auth,
                developerKey='myapikey1234')
```

you can see my json file here:
[build_response_data.json](https://gist.github.com/p3dr0migue1/2a4e8ec94de6fb93bc4e)

the problem happens in the line 253 of the function `_retrieve_discovery_doc` in the file `googleapiclient/discovery.py`

I just cant seem to understand what's going on..can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

To anwser my own question and to help others in the same boat, the problem was that the funtion `_retrieve_discovery_doc` tries to load the content as json as per in the line 253:

```
service = json.loads(content)
```

but because I was not opening the file and reading its contents, json was actually trying to load the url as json.

So the solution for the first part was change the HttpMockSequence to:

```
http_auth = HttpMockSequence([
    ({'status': '200'}, open(build_response, 'rb').read()),
    ({'status': '200'}, open(request_data, 'rb').read())
])
```

Then to return the data from the `request_data` file you do:

```
site_url = 'www.example.com'
body = {
    'startDate': '2015-09-11',
    'endDate': '2015-12-12',
    'dimensions': ['date']
}
build_response_data = self.datafile('build_response_data.json')
request_data = self.datafile('saved_request_data.json')
http_auth = HttpMockSequence([
    ({'status': '200'}, open(build_response_data, 'rb').read()),
    ({'status': '200'}, open(request_data, 'rb').read())
])

service = build('webmasters',
                'v3',
                http=http_auth,
                developerKey='myapikey1234')
service.searchanalytics().query(siteUrl=site_url, body=body).execute()
```

Hopefully this will help someone else.